# OpenLayers how do I stop propagation of pointer in OpenLayers 6

Tags: typescript, openlayers, openlayers-6, angular-openlayers

I'm upgrading to OpenLayers 6 and the code that previously worked

```
  import { MapBrowserPointerEvent as olMapBrowserPointerEvent } from 'ol/events/Event';

  const simpleLineInteraction: PointerInteraction = new PointerInteraction({
  handleDownEvent: handleDownEventHandler,
  handleDragEvent: handleDragEventHandler,
  handleUpEvent: handleUpEventHandler,
  stopDown: stopDownHandler
  });
  function stopDownHandler(evt: olMapBrowserPointerEvent) {
  return false;
  }
```

has stopped working for the stopDownHandler

The code I'm trying to implement is

```
import  MapBrowserEvent  from 'ol/MapBrowserEvent';
const simpleLineInteraction: PointerInteraction = new PointerInteraction({
handleDownEvent: handleDownEventHandler,
handleDragEvent: handleDragEventHandler,      
handleUpEvent: handleUpEventHandler,
stopDown: stopDownHandler
});
function stopDownHandler(evt: MapBrowserEvent<MouseEvent>) {
return false;
}
```

I've also tried using the type "UIEvent" in stopDownHandler and tried just setting it to false...the OpenLayers docs say it needs a function and the new pattern doesn't throw errors for any other handlers but 'stopDownHandler' i.e (

```
function handleDownEventHandler(evt: MapBrowserEvent<MouseEvent>) {
if (evt.originalEvent.buttons !== 2) {
downClick = evt.coordinate;
return true;
} else { return false; }
}
```

) works

I receive the error

> Type '(evt: MapBrowserEvent) => boolean' is not assignable to type '(arg0: boolean) => boolean'.
> Types of parameters 'evt' and 'arg0' are incompatible.
> Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'MapBrowserEvent'.ts(2322)

when using type UIEvent and error

> Type '(evt: MapBrowserEvent) => boolean' is not assignable to type '(arg0: boolean) => boolean'.
> Types of parameters 'evt' and 'arg0' are incompatible.
> Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'MapBrowserEvent'.ts(2322)

when using type MouseEvent...even though type mouse event works for the other handlers.

The OpenLayers documentation doesn't give a good example of how to use this and I can't find a good explanation in any of the "Upgrade" documentation how to change this so it will work.

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: If it is working for mouse but not pointer do you need a polyfill? https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/releases/tag/v6.4.0

Comment: It's not really about if it works or not...it doesn't build.  I'll update the question with this info

Answer (score 0):

Changing evt: MapBrowserEvent to arg0: boolean made the error go away but this does not seem like a good solution...it actually seems like a bug.